# "Magic" in its descriptive role

Tags: adjectives, style-manuals, minimal-pairs

[Fowler reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA498&dq=%22The%20two%20words%20compete%20with%20one%20another%20in%20all%20the%20main%20senses%2C%20%E2%80%98relating%20to%20magic%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98produced%20by%20or%20as%20if%20by%20magic%E2%80%99%2C%20and%20%E2%80%98wonderful%E2%80%99%2C%20although%20in%20certain%20fixed%20expressions%20such%20as%20magic%20carpet%2C%20magic%20circle%2C%20magic%20lantern%2C%20and%20magic%20square%20only%20magic%20is%20used.%20When%20used%20in%20its%20descriptive%20role%2C%20magic%20still%20behaves%20more%20like%20a%20noun%20than%20an%20adjective%2C%20which%20is%20to%20say%20that%20it%20cannot%20be%20preceded%20by%20very%2C%20extremely%2C%20etc.%2C%20and%20does%20not%20have%20a%20comparative%22&hl=es&pg=PA498#v=onepage&q=%22The%20two%20words%20compete%20with%20one%20another%20in%20all%20the%20main%20senses,%20%E2%80%98relating%20to%20magic%E2%80%99,%20%E2%80%98produced%20by%20or%20as%20if%20by%20magic%E2%80%99,%20and%20%E2%80%98wonderful%E2%80%99,%20although%20in%20certain%20fixed%20expressions%20such%20as%20magic%20carpet,%20magic%20circle,%20magic%20lantern,%20and%20magic%20square%20only%20magic%20is%20used.%20When%20used%20in%20its%20descriptive%20role,%20magic%20still%20behaves%20more%20like%20a%20noun%20than%20an%20adjective,%20which%20is%20to%20say%20that%20it%20cannot%20be%20preceded%20by%20very,%20extremely,%20etc.,%20and%20does%20not%20have%20a%20comparative%22&f=false)

> **Magic(al)**: The two words compete with one another in all the main senses, ‘relating to magic’, ‘produced by or as if by magic’, and
> ‘wonderful’, although in certain fixed expressions such as *magic
> carpet* only *magic* is used. When used in its **descriptive role**,
> *magic* still behaves more like a noun than an adjective, which is to say that it cannot be preceded by *very, extremely*, etc., and does
> not have a comparative.

What "descriptive role" is the author referring to, and as opposed to what other(s)?

Answer (score -1):

*Descriptive role* is not necessarily a set linguistic expression; it refers to the ***literal meaning*** of ***magic*** as opposed to the *figurative meaning.*

> A ***descriptive*** area of study is one that is based on ***saying what its
> subject is really like***, rather than on developing theories about it. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/descriptive))

The literal, descriptive meaning of ***magic*** is indeed:

> the use of special powers to make things happen that would usually be impossible, such as in stories for children ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/magic)).

With this meaning, it is [more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=magic_ADJ%2C%20magic_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmagic_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmagic_NOUN%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmagic_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmagic_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) used as a noun than as an adjective:

[image]

Comment: One wonders just how literal a meaning _magic_ can have.

Comment: @JohnLawler Good point. There is however a difference between "magic" as _supernatural power_ and "magic" as _wonderfully beautiful_.

Comment: There certainly can be, but not necessarily for all speakers.

Comment: I'd say that 'descriptive' is being used by Fowler (et al?) to mean 'modifying [as opposed to nominal]'.  'A magic carpet / wand / moment.' Not "Timmy Cowper was never very good at magic". Terminology has been worryingly ill-defined over the years.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would have thought so, but then he says it behaves like a noun. It's an adjective in "magic carpet/wand/moment".

Comment: But he's still right that you can't say "very magic carpet" or "Alladin's carpet is more magic than my rug"

Comment: @Barmar The jury could still be out on 'magic' used attributively. There's still a paper kicking about trying to pin down the POS of 'steel' in 'steel bridge'; I don't think anything has superseded it. Note that it's a given that nouns as well as adjectives can pre-modify head nouns (yellow ball; cricket ball). // Attributive nouns are ungradeable, don't take 'very' etc, but then the same behaviour occurs with classifier adjectives (*'a very chemical reaction', *'a more nuclear explosion').